# getaddrinfo unable to resolve host

Tags: python, macos, dns, osx-snow-leopard, urllib2

I'm having a weird problem. I have this Python application and when I try to open a url in the application, for instance `urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com", None)` I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

However when I do the same thing on the python command line interpreter it works fine. The same python executable is being used for both the application and the command line.

`nslookup google.com` seems to work fine. I opened up wireshark and it looks like when the application tries to open `google.com` only a mDNS query goes out for `"My-Name-MacBook-Pro.local"`. However, when the command line tries to open `google.com` a regular DNS query goes out for `"google.com"` I found if I hardcoded Google's IP in `/etc/hosts` then the request from the application finally started working.

It seems something weird must be altering how the application resolves domain names, but I have no idea what could be doing this.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6.7 and Python 2.6.

**Edit**: I am not using a proxy to access the internet

Comment: Are you actually using `urllib` or `urllib2`? Please correct the tags on your question if `urllib2` is wrong.

Comment: are you using a proxy to access the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Just see that you don't have HTTP_PROXY environment variable set which is preventing this. (In which case, that would be a bad error message. Given the proper directory and try again, like

```
import urllib
r = urlib.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
print r.read()
```